# Typed Array as Function Parameter not possible - why?

Tags: typescript

Why is this possible:

```
interface MyInterface{

    aggregate: (Array) => Array<string>;
}
```

But not this:

```
interface MyInterface{

    aggregate: (Array<string>) => Array<string>;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because the first one does not do what it appears to do. Your intention was probably to define a function with a parameter of type `Array`. While in actuality you defined a function with a parameter named `Array` of type any

If you don't specify parameter types they are assumed to be `any`. You can be warned about this if you specify the `noImplicitAny` flag.

Answer (score 3):

Please read the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html).

TypeScript don't support writing function parameter type alone, you have to provide its parameter name.

```
interface MyInterface{

    aggregate: (args: Array<string>) => Array<string>;
}
```